# Work of Ted Kaczynski

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, math-history

I hope this question is not too crazy sounding, but I was wondering if anyone is familiar with the work of Ted Kaczynski (or even has cited/used it before).
After reading in Lars Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis* and Serge Lang's book by the same name, I became interested in some of the historic results in complex analysis.

I know that Kaczynski did work in the field of complex analysis and specifically geometric function theory. From what I have gathered, he was actually rather brilliant as a research mathematician. What in specific did he research and how are his results used today? (If at all).

Again, I do not want to know about his political views or his history as the Unabomber. I am only interested in the utility of his mathematics.

Comment: There is something of a bibliography [here](http://homepages.rpi.edu/~bulloj/tjk/tjk.html) with summaries. I can't say anything about their quality. A lot of it is in AMS journals and is hence relatively easy to track down online to read for yourself. This kind of thing seems somewhat different from the sort of analysis done in introductory complex analysis texts, though. You can still see his name on the Sumner Myers Award for Best Thesis plaque on the first floor of East Hall in Ann Arbor and my understanding is that he got a job at Berkeley after that, so he was probably pretty good.

Comment: Assistant professorship at Cal for a couple of years, which he then resigned.

Comment: There's a nice description here, in particular Andres's answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49395/behaviour-of-power-series-on-their-circle-of-convergence/49411#49411

Comment: I wonder if complex analysts are somehow predisposed to murder.  See [André Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Bloch_(mathematician))

Comment: @JairTaylor interesting! I guess it's a good thing I do group theory for a living.

Comment: @Vladhagen: Definitely, Galois was a terrible shooter :).

Comment: Completely off topic but there was actually another homicidal mathematician named Ted, namely Ted Streleski. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Streleski Streleski was a perennial grad student who could never finish a thesis, and finally he bludgeoned his advisor to death with a hammer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

T. Kaczynski has published 6 papers in 4 years (1965-69) which can be considered as a good beginning of a promising career. According to Mathscinet database,
one of his papers was cited 4 times (2 of them by himself), and three were cited one time each (two by himself). Mathscinet does not count all citations but most of them.

I am somewhat familiar with the subject of his work. I would not call it "brilliant", but qualify it as average PhD graduating from a good university.

Remark. That two well known serial killers among mathematicians were both doing complex variables, is a coincidence, on my opinion:-)
(The other one was [Andre Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Bloch_(mathematician)) who was a really brilliant mathematician, but unfortunately, insane.)

Comment: Wait, there are two?

Comment: O wait, the other one is mentioned in the comments on the original post, never mind

Comment: @Vincent 1: No, the person mentioned in the comments was not known as a mathematician. I added the name of the second one to my answer.